# Windows Form C# - How can I use textBoxes created programmatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have created 100 textboxes programmatically using the following code:

```
for (int c = 0; c < 100; c++)
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.Text = "ADI" + i;
    tb.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
    Point p = new Point(20, 30 * i);
    tb.Location = p;
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(tb);
    i++;
}
```

Now I want to retrieve/add some data to them.
Example:

```
textBox1.Text = "a";
```

but the program doesn't recognize `textBox1`, because actually it doesn't exist.
How can I solve it?

Comment: you have to keep your own references to those textboxes somewhere

Comment: maybe tb[c].Text = "a" solve the problem so you select which textbox do you want

Comment: `var txt = new TextBox() { Name = "textBox100" }; this.Controls.Add(txt); txt.BringToFront(); this.Controls["textBox100"].Text = $"I'm {txt.Name}";`. So, you could store the Controls' references in a `List<Control>`, or the Controls' names in a `List<string>`. `[Control].Controls` is already such a List, you can use that. Or use a more complex custom class object to keep track of GUI controls, adding useful features to handle events and single them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WinForms designer and you use Partial classes. You work on one part of the class. The Designer on another. And at compile time, what you each wrote is put together. The designer created code is run with the call of `InitializeComponents().` Accordingly, the designer can do nothing that you could not also do. It also creates stuff "Dynamic at runtime".

In this case the solution is fairly simple - store references to those Boxes as you create them:

```
//class scope variable
TextBox[] createdBoxes = new TextBox[100];

//wichever function you run that in
for (int c = 0; c < 100; c++)
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    //Position code omited for readability
    createdBoxes[c] = tb;
}
```

There is one caveat however: Do not store information in the GUI classes. It is a rather common mistake of using that array of TextBoxes you created to store the data. That will only make retreiving and re-setting that data unessesarily hard. Consider storing the Data in code behind, making the GUI classes merely a *representation* of the game state.

Also with that many TextBoxes, you are propably deep in [XY Problem territory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

You could assign Names for each of the textboxes. For example,

```
 TextBox tb = new TextBox();
 tb.Name = $"textBox{i}";
```

And when you need to assign a value to a particular textbox, you could use Linq to search for the particular Control. For example,

```
panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Single(x => x.Name == "textBox1").Text = "New Value";
```